# jquery each does not work well, sometimes it gives the good results and sometimes it dont

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website where before adding a product to the cart, the user has to select addons. These addons are divided in 2 parts. I group with select box addons (when only 1 option is needed) and 1 group with multiple addons, where the user can select multiple checkboxes. the checkboxes work fine, except for the select box options. The select boxes are automaticly populated. (smarty):

```
            {if $menuaddonslist[add].mainaddonsname neq '' && $menuaddonslist[add].mainaddonsnamecnt eq 1}
                {$objSearchDetails->menuSubAddonsList($menuaddonslist[add].addonparentid,$menuaddonslist[add].menuaddons_menuid)}
                    <div class="single" id="singleAddon-{$menuaddonslist[add].addonparentid}">
                    <span class="addonTitle">{$menuaddonslist[add].mainaddonsname|stripslashes}</span>
                    <input type="hidden" name="singleopt" class="singleopt" id="singleopt" value="single">
                    <select class="popNameInput" name="addonstype_{$menuSubaddonslist_cnt}_{$smarty.section.subadd.rownum}" style="border: 1px solid #dedede;margin-bottom:15px;width:230px;">
                    {section name="subadd" loop=$menuSubaddonslist}
                        {if $menuSubaddonslist[subadd].subaddonsname neq ''}
                            {if $menuaddonslist[add].mainaddonsnamecnt eq '1'}
                            <option value="{$menuSubaddonslist[subadd].menuaddons_id}">
                              {$menuSubaddonslist[subadd].subaddonsname|ucfirst|stripslashes}
                                {if $menuSubaddonslist[subadd].menuaddons_priceoption eq 'Paid'} 
                                (+&nbsp;&#8364;{$menuSubaddonslist[subadd].menuaddons_price} )
                                {/if}
                            </option>
                            {/if}
                         {/if}
                    {/section}
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear:both"></div>
```

This outputs a minimum of 1 select box, up to whatever amount with their values. All work fine.

Now when the user hits Add to cart, all these addons are added to the cart. In javascript I have 2 arrays witch contain the values (id's) of the addons

Now here is the strange part. On the website when i open the popup and see the addons and hit add to cart, sometimes it works.. and sometimes the "addons" var is undefined... i can open the same popup 10 times, and in those 10 times 2 times the addons will be added fine and the other 8 times the addon array is undefined again I dont get it here is the code:

```
//Add To Cart
function addToMenu(resfea){

    var menuid        = $("#menuid").val();
    var resid         = $("#restid").val();
    var quantity      = $("#qty").val();
    //var menuspl_ins   = $("#splins").val();
    var menuspl_ins       = check_undefined(menuspl_ins);
    //var offer       = $("#offer").val();
    var offer         = check_undefined(offer);

        $.post(jssitebaseUrl+'/ajaxFile.php',{"menuid":menuid,"action":"checkCategoryName"},function(response){
        //alert(response);

            var sizeoption  = $("#sizeoption").val();

            if(sizeoption == 'fixed'){
                var menuprice     = $("#menuprice").val();
            }

            var addonstype1   = $("#addonstype1").val();
            //alert(addonstype1);
            if(addonstype1 > 0){

                var multipleoption   = $("#multipleopt").val();
                var singleoption     = $("#singleopt").val();
                var singleoptioncnt  = $("#singleoptcnt").val();

                if(singleoption == 'single'){
                    var AddonstypeSingle=[];

                    $("select[name^=addonstype_] option:selected").each(function(){
                        //var singleSelect = $("select").val;
                        if (this.value != "") {
                    ---->THIS MUST ALWAYS ALERT SOME ID WHEN THERE ARE SELECT BOXES//alert(this.value);
                            AddonstypeSingle.push(this.value);
                        }
                    });
                }

                if(multipleoption == 'multiple'){
                //Check Box Value
                    var totaddonsid = document.orderpop.addonstype.length;
                    if(totaddonsid == undefined){
                        if(document.orderpop.addonstype.checked==true){
                            addonstype=document.orderpop.addonstype.value;
                        }
                        var Addonsmul=addonstype;   
                        if( Addonsmul !='' ){
                            var Addonstypemultiple = Addonsmul+',';
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(totaddonsid > 0){
                            var addonstype=new Array();
                            var j=0;
                            for(var i=0;i<totaddonsid;i++){
                                if(document.orderpop.addonstype[i].checked==true){
                                    addonstype[j]=document.orderpop.addonstype[i].value;
                                    j++;
                                }
                            }
                            var Addonsmul=addonstype;   
                            if( Addonsmul !='' ){
                                var Addonstypemultiple = Addonsmul+',';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(Addonstypemultiple == undefined){
                    var Addons = AddonstypeSingle;
                }
                else if(AddonstypeSingle == undefined){
                    var Addons = Addonstypemultiple;
                }
                else{
                    var Addons = Addonstypemultiple+AddonstypeSingle;
                }
            }
            //alert(Addons); <-- RETURNS UNDEFINED WHEN THE SELECTBOX VALUES ARE NOT ALERTED


            Addons              = check_undefined(Addons);
            menuprice           = check_undefined(menuprice);
            $('.restaurantMenuAddtocartmm').load(jssitebaseUrl+"/ajaxAction.php?menuid="+menuid+"&offer="+offer+"&resid="+resid+"&menuprice="+menuprice+"&Addons="+Addons+"&quantity="+quantity+"&action=addtoItem", { 'menuspl_ins':menuspl_ins });

        });
        return false;
}
```

var AddonstypeSingle=[] can not be empty if there are select boxes, but the strange thing is.. sometimes it alerts the ids just fine and other times it gives no alert, or a undefined one. So for some reason the each does not work all the time like it should...

I tried everything but for some reason it adds the addons just fine, and then it just dont add them etc. It took me hours and i still have no clue, I hope someone can lead me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

This is a closure problem.

In this part:

```
 if(Addonstypemultiple == undefined){
                var Addons = AddonstypeSingle;
            }
            else if(AddonstypeSingle == undefined){
                var Addons = Addonstypemultiple;
            }
            else{
                var Addons = Addonstypemultiple+AddonstypeSingle;
            }
        }
        //alert(Addons); <-- RETURNS UNDEFINED WHEN THE SELECTBOX VALUES ARE NOT ALERTED
```

You are defining the var Addons within the function of an if. This will not be available to your alert function. I could suggest a simple solution of:

```
 var Addons;

 if(Addonstypemultiple == undefined){
                Addons = AddonstypeSingle;
            }
            else if(AddonstypeSingle == undefined){
                Addons = Addonstypemultiple;
            }
            else{
                Addons = Addonstypemultiple+AddonstypeSingle;
            }
        }
        alert(Addons);
```

Comment: no, this is not the issue, altough its better like you said. But where it goes wrong is the var AddonstypeSingle=[]; this should be filled when there are select boxesbut sometimes it does and sometimes it doesnt

Comment: @rZaaaa Did you try this though? You will get UNDEFINED for a var you have not set.